# Database request with Contao?

Tags: php, database

I´m trying to connect to a table but I only get a white page, am I doing something wrong?

```
$this->import('myDB');
$result = $this->Database->prepare("SELECT * FROM partnerpool")->execute();
echo $result->numRows; 
echo $result->id;
while($result->next())
{
    echo $result->id;
}
```

Description: http://de.contaowiki.org/Datenbank_Klasse_verwenden

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use: `$this->import('Database');` to use the database defined in your localconfig.php.
You can't import an external database!

You can also write:

```
$dbObj = \Database::getInstance()->prepare("SELECT * FROM partnerpool")
        ->execute();  

if ($dbObj->numRows > 0)
{
   var_dump( $dbObj->fetchAllAssoc() );
}
```